# How to enable expire web content in IIS using powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, server, automation, administrator

I'm doing automation for server setup using powershell script. I want to enable the expire web content and set it to After and value should be set to 1 DAY

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the powershell script.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache" -name "cacheControlMode" -value "UseMaxAge"

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache" -name "cacheControlMaxAge" -value "1.00:00:00"
```

Comment: what if you want to do at server level not to any specific site?

Comment: Thank you, for server level just had to set -pspath to 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'